# wpf stylus mouse event

Tags: wpf, windows-7, onclick

When button1 gets tapped by the stylus test method gets called twice, even though I am setting the Handled property in the stylusdown event. Is there a way to have the stylus event not propegate a secondary button click event?

```
namespace DialogTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            test(sender, e);
        }

        private void button1_StylusDown(object sender, StylusDownEventArgs e)
        {
            test(sender, e);
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void test(object e, EventArgs env)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString(), env.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("clicking");
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at this [MSDN Input overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010.aspx) documentation. you will see the fact the both events are called.

From above link:

> Because the stylus can act as a mouse, applications that support only mouse input can still obtain some level of stylus support automatically. When the stylus is used in such a manner, the application is given the opportunity to handle the appropriate stylus event and then handles the corresponding mouse event. In addition, higher-level services such as ink input are also available through the stylus device abstraction.

Since it does give you the order the events are called you can create a Boolean variable, set it in the `StylusDown EventHandler`, then check in your `Button_Click EventHandler` if it is true, set it to false then exit the Handler.

something like this.

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    bool StylusDown;
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(StylusDown)
        {
            StylusDown=false;
            return;
        }

        test(sender, e);
    }

    private void button1_StylusDown(object sender, StylusDownEventArgs e)
    {
        StylusDown =true;
        test(sender, e);
    }

    private void test(object e, EventArgs env)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString(), env.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine("clicking");
    }


}
```

There may be a better way of accomplishing this, but this is was the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Thank you very much kind sir, I have implemented your solution and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

MouseEventArgs has a property called StylusDevice that will be not null if the event originated from a stylus or touch event.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.StylusDevice != null) return;
    ...
}
```